# Convert loop into mathematical equation

Tags: java, math, logic, algebra

How would I represent this for loop in a mathematical equation?

```
double n = 1;
    double x = Math.pow(3, n);
    for(double i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x = x + Math.pow(3, i);
    }
```

Sorry wrote it in Java in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop can be simplifed to

```
x= (pow(3,n)-1)/2
```

I have double checked this here:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+pow%283%2Ci%29+for+i+from+0+to+%28n-1%29

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much! Would you mind explaining how you got there?

Comment: It is sum of geometric series.

Comment: But not with the initialization of x as given! This would be (pow(3,n+1)-1)/2.